infinity login and password in tty`s
Hi I will be so grateful if somebody can help me with my problem.
I`ve been using arch for an 1-2 months, trying to learn about this thing. So, I have login and password thing directly in tty, without any manager, after logging in - hyprland automatically starts up. But yesterday 09.10.24 updated system as usual with sudo pacman -Syu (didn't see anything wrong after update) than turned off the laptop with shutdown now and turned on, tried to log in to arch but after entering login and password it clears off so I can do it again, again and again on tty1,tty2...
Found some solutions, like to add "splash" in grub menu, going to root with pendrive with arch iso but nothing changed.
Current Arch Linux 6.11.2-arch1-1
